# How do I get more rubies?

Tags: mario-kart-tour

This being a f2p game, I know I can get more rubies with real world money, but is there a way to get any more in the game without paying money?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the start of the game you are granted 20 rubies and forced to spend 5 as part of the tutorial. After that, you can gain more rubies from:

- **Leveling up** - Each time you gain enough experience to level up you are given an award. Sometimes the award is rubies.
- **Tour gifts** - Between certain cups you are given a tour gift. Rubies are sometimes contained in these gifts.
- **Rank-eligible cups** - Some cups are "rank-eligible" and will grant you rubies for placing in the top spots.
- **Daily login bonuses** - Rubies are awarded every few days.
- **Challenges** - After clearing 7 cups you will unlock challenges which sometimes award rubies for completion.